# Dynamic enum return based on condition

Tags: java, enums

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public enum ErrorDemo {

    PCAT_DEMO("PC01", "this demo", "BAD_AUTH", "TMN"),
    PCAT_DEMO1("PC03", "this demo1", "NOT FOUND", "TOP"),
    PCAT_DEMO("PC02", "this demo", "NOT AVAILABLE", "TMN");

    private final String errorCode;
    private final String errorMessage;
    private final String errorMessagePattern;
    private final String systemErrorSource;

    // This method will return specific enum which field is matching with the passed arguments
    public static ErrorConstants fromErrorPatternt(String errorPattern, String errorSource) {
        ...
    }
}
```

calling from here
ErrorConstants err = ErrorConstants.fromErrorPatternt(errorMsg, "TMN");

where the errorMsg to be matched errorMessagePattern  and "TMN" to be matched with systemErrorSource, then it will return the specific enum

Comment: Do I get your code right, you want the fromErrorPatternt to return the Enum value depending on the filter and not a 'dynamic' enum?

Comment: You want an `if` statement? What is `ErrorConstants`?

Comment: @ThomasW.  yes you are correct.

Comment: @Dave Newton Sorry its ErrorDemo the enum class name.

Comment: The answer of MC Emperor with the lambda looks really good...thumbs up...as an alternative you could store the enums in a map. Key could be a combination of the pattern and source. Retrieving the enum is then easily possible with a get on the map. If you are interested, just let me know and I will provide a sample code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could walk over all enum values, and then match them with the given values:

```java
return Arrays.stream(ErrorConstants.values())
    .filter(ec -> Objects.equals(errorPattern, ec.getErrorMessagePattern()) && Objects.equals(errorSource, ec.getSystemErrorSource()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow();
```

Regarding `findFirst` — it could be that multiple enums match. `findFirst()` is just returning the first one. If it is desired to have just a single element matching the errorPattern-errorSource combination, then you have to manually ensure that.

If nothing matches, then it throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

---

A classic (enhanced) for loop would look like this:

```java
for (var ec : ErrorConstants.values()) {
    if (Objects.equals(errorPattern, ec.getErrorMessagePattern()) && Objects.equals(errorSource, ec.getSystemErrorSource())) {
        return ec;
    }
}
throw new NoSuchElementException();
```

---

<sup>Note: Your question mentions both `ErrorDemo` and `ErrorConstants`. I assume this is a mistake and they refer to the same thing.</sup>

Comment: The above code worked fine ##Help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the answer works out for you, give it an upvote and mark the question as solved ;)